# How to set environment variable in supervisord using output from a file

Tags: linux, environment-variables, supervisord

What is the good way to set environment variable in supervisord using output from a file?
I need like:

```
[program:prog1]
command=prog1 -param1 -param2
environment=PASSWORD=`cat .password`
```

I can use an additional script, but perhaps the better way exists:

```
[program:prog1]
command=start-prog1
```

start-prog1:

```
export PASSWORD=`cat .password`
start-prog1
```

Answer (score -1):

### Environment variables that are present in the environment at the time that supervisord is started can be used in the configuration file using the Python string expression syntax %(ENV_X)s:

http://supervisord.org/configuration.html

You can use (in Bash)

```
export PASSWORD1=$(cat .password)
```

Then use this in the configuration file

```
environment = PASSWORD=%(PASSWORD1)s
```

Comment: I need to use different environment variables for each process, because some process can be started on a host and each process should have own password, that is impossible if I'll use one scrip for exporting variable and supervizord for starting processes.

Comment: This **does not work** in Supervisor 3.2.

Comment: @Newb do you know how to fix it in `3.2`?